# fourier transforms with Woflram Alpha

Tags: fourier-analysis, mathematica

I'm studying Fourier transform at the moment and I've noticed some weird irregularities between my textbook and Wolfram Alpha's answers.

Say I ask Wolfram the following:

> *fourier transform delta(t-1)*

My textbook claims the fourier transform of this is:

> exp(-j*2pi*f)

but then Woflram says otherwise:

[image]

It's not only with this specific transform. I noticed it with several others. Why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because there are several conventions followed in defining the Fourier Transform.
By default, Mathematica computes
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t
$$
when you ask for the Fourier Transform.
But your Textbook defines it as
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t
$$
For getting the Fourier Transform defined as above, Try
`FourierTransform[DiracDelta[t-1],t,\[Omega], FourierParameters -> {1,-1}]`

You can read more about the different conventions and their corresponding parameters in the documentation.

Comment: I'm rather new to all this so I didn't realize there were different conventions. Thanks1

Comment: @codedude Edited my answer with more explanation about the conventions

Comment: interesting. I'll have to look more into this